# Laravel routing two optional one after another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

First, I would gladly accept suggestions on that title, because I am not sure how to explain my issue in one row.

I have a route that looks like that

```
Route::get ('/i/{group?}/{name?}', 'Controller@index')->name('name');
```

Problem is when I go to `/i//myname` it throws a route exception.

I made both conditional because I have strict validations within the controller. I want to keep that structure, but what route should I make to make both optional variables work ?

Ex. When you open `/i//myname` to redirect you to the **select group** page, so as `/i/group//` or `/i/group/`

Comment: what is the exception you are getting

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest going for optional paramaters. What I mean is you define your route like this:

```
Route::get ('/i', 'Controller@index')->name('name');
```

Then you put your parameters to the url like this:

```
http://localhost/i?group=1&name=stack
```

From your controller you do:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('group') {
        $group = $request->group;
    }
    ...
}
```

You get the idea. This might help but may not be what you are looking for.